# how do you link two users in Firebase where the "admin user" can see all of the data of the other user

Tags: firebase, nosql

I have a firebase structure question:

I have an app that tracks a kids study habits and sends a report of it the parent.

My structure is as follows: I have a users collection and I use the uid to diferentiate every user in there. I store all of the users data in relation to their studies but also their email address.

**Question 1:** How do I structure the database so a parent can link to their kids data and see all of it but not the other way around?

**Question 2:** How would it work with consent? i.e the kid consenting to the parent receiving their data so you can just link to someone and see their data?

Comment: There are actually two questions in you SO post. For the first one, you should probably adopt a role-based access control strategy, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims?hl=en&authuser=0

Answer (score -1):

To link two users in Firebase and grant the "**admin user**" access to another user's data, you can utilize Firebase Authentication and Firestore. Assign a role or a custom claim to the admin user using Firebase Authentication. In Firestore, structure your data to include a field specifying the user's role or ID. Implement security rules to allow the admin user read access to all users' data. This ensures that the admin user can view information from other users while maintaining security. Always handle sensitive data carefully and follow best practices for Firebase security to protect user privacy.

Comment: my apologies I forgot to mention the admin can also be a student, have their own study data as well as theirs kids, but I don't want a parent to have access to every students data only their own kids data.